# Error in reading int value from CSV using tFileInputDelimited Error: For input string: "10617,,,,,"

Tags: talend

I am new to Talend I am trying to read a CSV file and sorting it based on an integer value.
Please find below my csv sample input

*description;industry;level;size;linecode;value

Business spent significant time and resource on supplier factors;FIN;0;6–19 employees;LC0301;10617

Business spent significant time and resource on labour factors;FIN;0;6–19 employees;LC0302;16395

Business spent significant time and resource on technological / equipment factors;FIN;0;6–19 employees;LC0303;7401

Business spent significant time and resource on financing factors;FIN;0;6–19 employees;LC0304;4896

Business spent significant time and resource on customer related factors;FIN;0;6–19 employees;LC03051;3101*

I am trying to read it using tFileInputDelimited.Schema which I defined is
[Schema Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS7iP.jpg)

When i run the job.I am getting below error.

```
Starting job SortCSVFile at 11:24 26/02/2019.

******[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3949
[statistics] connected
For input string: "10617,,,,,"
For input string: "16395,,,,,"
For input string: "7401,,,,,"
For input string: "4896,,,,,"
For input string: "3101,,,,,"
[statistics] disconnected
Job SortCSVFile ended at 11:24 26/02/2019. [exit code=0]******
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.I **select "Advance Separator(for numbers)" checkbox in Advanced Settings tab of tFileInputDelimeter**. Thanks.I posted this answer because it might be helpful to new learners like me.